# httperf burst­length when using wsesslog

Tags: testing, httperf, stress

I am trying to use httperf to stress test a server using the following syntax

```
    httperf --hog --client=0/1 --server myserver.com \
--wsesslog=2000,2,mysessions.cfg --max-piped-calls 5 --rate 150
```

this should create 2000 sessions at a rate of 150 req/s

mysessions.cfg contains

```
/path1/url think=2.0
/common/css/base.css
/images/image.png
```

..

My problem is I would like to specify a burst-lenght (concurrent calls inside session) greater than 2 but I always get

> Maximum connect burst length: 2

the ­­burst­length=N is not usable with wsessionlog and I didn't see any way to specify it inside mysessions.cfg

Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert, but I thought that call-burst mimic the browser first request to select the HTML page then the objects imbedded in it, hence is two call-bursts. Are you thinking pipeline HTTP calls? those do increase the number of calls per connection

Comment: This answer is somewhat borderline but does provide the beginnings of a solution. It's usually better to ask for feedback using comments when you have enough reputation to do so, but this question has been neglected and the rest of us obviously aren't doing that for you. +1 for picking up our slack.